# jQuery CSS not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have the following set of conditions in a 'on submit' function in my script:

```
    if (required) {
        if (upload) {
            $('.upload-button').css({ 'display' : 'none' });
            $('.uploading').css({ 'display' : 'block' });
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

The two CSS lines are running correctly in all browsers except Safari.

Does anyone know of any reason this wouldn't be work in Safari? I have cleared cache etc.

Comment: Use `show()` and `hide()`

Comment: When you say it's 'in a on submit' function, do you mean a `submit()` event of a form, or the `click()` of a submit button? Also, can you provide more detail that 'it doesn't work'. Why does it not work? What do you expect to happen? etc

Comment: The code looks correct. Are you sure the code gets executed? Maybe there is another problem that stops the script getting there.

Comment: yeah, that seems to [run fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/2prkbztm/) in safari

Comment: maybe you can try to remove quotes from display part. From 'display' to just display.


`$('.upload-button').css({ display : 'none' });`


`$('.uploading').css({ display : 'block' });`

Comment: @Ted I have tried all of the above and nothing is working.
I have the code applied within $('form#publishForm').submit(function() { });

Comment: @ccdavies Can you provide the html for the form, along with the whole script, so we can duplicate it--or better yet provide a fiddle. [Here's a fiddle to get you started](http://jsfiddle.net/gyympam0/). Just add your html in (and the rest of the script) and update it--I simplified the script you posted just a touch.

Answer (score -2):

When you add Css like this, it goes inline.
It is not a good practice, may be that is causing some issue.
Try doing this with css classes:

Make 2 classes in our CSS:

```css
.hide{display:none;}
.show{display:block;}
```

Now inside your js code:

```js
$('.upload-button').removeClass('show').addClass('hide);
$('.uploading').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
```